# Should i use noun or verb as entity name in java?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

While writing model names what care should i take (i mean, should i use nouns or verbs)? I didn't find any online reference for the same. Lets take example, I have to write model for complain, so should i go with complain or complaint?

Comment: Classes should be nouns - [Chapter 9 of the Java Coding Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) - but you might want to define what "entity" means in your context. Gut feeling is, it should be a noun, as you "have a" complaint, not that "you are" complaining

Answer (score 2):

Usually noun is used for model name since it symbolizes an object, so `complaint` instead of `complain`. Verb is generally used for function name, service name, etc. However, there is no strict rules about it, as long as it makes sense and help other people to understand what does that entity represent.

Answer (score 0):

In OOP, a class typically represents a real world object, i.e. a noun.
A class has attributes (class level variables) and behaviour (methods).
Since behaviour is a verb, we generally name methods as verbs.

Here is an example:-

```
class Complaint {                               // model class name is a noun    
    String message;                             // property is a noun
}

class ComplaintHandler {
    public void complain(Complaint complaint) { // method name is a verb
    }
}
```

[Wikipedia Naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)) state:-

> Class names should be nouns
>
> Methods should be verbs

These conventions can be relaxed for certain cases if it makes more sense and is more readable.